# Yocto project : How to add MYSQL to my Linux operating system image?

Tags: mysql, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, recipe

I built a Linux operating system image using Yocto project SUMO Branch.

I am searching how to add  **MySQL** database management system to my image.

I have added these to my **local.conf** file :

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " mysql5"
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_mysql5 = "mysql5"
```

But these don't add **MySQL** . Instead of that, I find **MARIADB** in my image.

How can I add MySQL ?

Comment: layers.openembedded.org says a mysql recipe has not existed for at least 7 years:  everyone else seems to be fine with mariadb. So you'd have to write a mysql recipe first (this is likely to be non-trivial -- see the mariadb recipe for a comparable example). I suggest really considering if mariadb would work for you too.

Comment: @JussiKukkonen does mariadb work for mysql application ? or I will find problems ?

Comment: According to this commit (https://git.congatec.com/yocto/meta-openembedded/commit/72e23c12296fbc77193898c38426add58d0c2d71), it's a straight-up replacement. Sorry for misleading you on IRC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include recipe name not the foldername. check with recipe name.